# How do you generate a random number with a pre-specified probability distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

I want to generate a random real number between 0 and 1 but not distributed uniformly but with a probability distribution say, `2 Sin[ pi x ]^2` which integrates to 1 and peaks at $x = 1/2$.

I tried looking for *Biased random variables* in the HELP tab, but it did not show any hits.

This is my PDF:

```
pdf = 2 Sin[Pi x]^2
```

Comment: Have you tried a `RandomVariate` of a `ProbabilityDistribution` with your chosen PDF function?

Comment: Please give actual code ..

Comment: This is a low-quality question. In the future, please make an effort to show due diligence. Provide a minimum working example of the code you have, tell us what have you tried, how did you search, and why the results were not satisfactory.

Comment: It's hard to provide code when you cannot spot the command that does the trick in the help menu. I tried looking for Biased random variables in the HELP tab, it did not show any hits ...

Comment: @QuasarSupernova if I Google [`"Mathematica" How do you generate a random number with a pre-specified probability distribution?`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Mathematica%22+How+do+you+generate+a+random+number+with+a+pre-specified+probability+distribution) (i.e the title you wrote) the first hit brings me to [Random Number Generation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html), which contain in the second paragraph already an explicit mention of `RandomVariate`, which could have been a good start.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[2 Sin[Pi x]^2, {x, 0, 1}];

SeedRandom[1]
sample = RandomVariate[dist, 500];

Show[Histogram[sample, 20, "PDF"], Plot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `PearsonChiSquareTest[sample, dist, "TestDataTable"]` results in $$\begin{array}{l|ll}
 \text{} & \text{Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
\hline
 \text{Pearson }\chi ^2 & 20.6 & 0.662195 \\
\end{array}$$ and does not confirm the accordance between `sample` and `dist`.

Comment: @user64494 Try comparing the P-value obtained using `dist` as the test distribution with that obtained using another test distribution on the same data (e.g. `NormalDistribution[]` or `UniformDistribution[]`) and see how the latter attempts result in much, much lower P-values.

Comment: @MarcoB: . Do you mean the results of `PearsonChiSquareTest[sample, dist, "TestDataTable"]` are incorrect? If so, I don't understand your arguments. Please, elaborate those.

Comment: @user64494 No. I suggest that the P-value you obtained is actually compatible with reasonable fit between the data and the proposed distribution. As a counterexample, I recommended running `PearsonChiSquareTest[sample, UniformDistribution[], "TestDataTable"]` to see an example of the kind of P-value that would be associated with a poor fit between data and test distribution.

Comment: @user64494, check `PearsonChiSquareTest[sample, dist, "TestConclusion"]`

Comment: @MarcoB:  You open an opened door. `sample` is not a sample from `UniformDistribution[]` and `PearsonChiSquareTest[sample, UniformDistribution[], "TestDataTable"]` demonstrates it. But `sample` is a big sample from `ProbabilityDistribution[2 Sin[Pi x]^2, {x, 0, 1}]` and the `PearsonChiSquareTest[sample, dist, "TestDataTable"]` should  confirm it but the test doesn't. Hope, I am clear.

Comment: @kglr. This produces "The null hypothesis that the data is distributed according to the ProbabilityDistribution[2 Sin[\[FormalX] \[Pi]]^2,{\[FormalX],0,1}] is not rejected at the 5 percent level based on the Pearson \[Chi]^2 test." and is much better than the histogram in your answer. However, `20.6` is too big.  There is a chance the error of the second kind is made.

Comment: 500 samples is not enough to reject any similar distribution, try `dist2=NormalDistribution[Mean[dist],StandardDeviation[dist] ]`, `PearsonChiSquareTest[smallsample, dist2, "ShortTestConclusion"]` gives `"Do not reject"`.  You need around 5000 samples to reject a `NormalDistribution` of the same `Mean` and `StandardDeviation`.

Answer (score 6):

Since your PDF already integrates to one over the range this is pretty straight-forward:

```
RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[2 Sin[Pi x]^2, {x, 0, 1}]]

(* 0.163801 *)
```